# Deploying an MVC 4 application programatically

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am thinking at the following scenario: I have a solution with a web application(containing some REST web services) and a console application which is responsible for monitoring the resources of the host server(CPU, RAM, etc.). I want to implement the following feature: when the console app sees that for example I get a value bigger than a given threshold(lets say the CPU usage is over 70%) to deploy automatically on a new machine(on the same network). This is probably something similar with the Azure environment, but I'm not sure because I've never used it(just watched some videos). Has anyone implemented something similar? Can this be done locally on my machine? Any hints and answers are greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Alex

Comment: Your question is not clear. What should be deployed? and Where? What should determine the deployment? Where is the console app running?

Comment: Hi, musefan. What should be deployed: the entire solution with all its containing projects. Where: on another IIS server which is hosted by another machine(not the actual one). What should determine the deployment: some threshold which I am monitoring(CPU usage, Memory Usage, etc.). Hope it`s clear now. :)